# ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf3' SQL/Oracle

Tags: python, sql, pandas, oracle

I'm trying to make an extraction from Oracle database, the query works fine but when I try to pass it to a DataFrame I receive an error.

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
    
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle as cx_Oracle

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(r'****','***', service_name='*****')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'***',password = '****',dsn=dsn_tns)

c = conn.cursor()
try:
    query = '''
select distinct th.tmhalucod ALUCOD,
                th.tmhespcod ESPCOD,
                NVL(KLS.CURSO_KLS, '#REGISTRO NOVO#') CURSO_KLS,
                ac.tmacod TURMA,
                th.tmhdisperiodo PERIODO_OFERTA

  from temphist th

  join aluncurs ac
    on th.tmhalucod = ac.alucod

  join v_alunsituatual v
    on v.alucod = ac.alucod
   and v.espcod = ac.espcod
   and v.pelcod = ac.pelcod

  join especial e
    on e.espcod = ac.espcod

  LEFT JOIN ROBERTOALMEIDA.DPAA_TB_DE_PARA_CURSO KLS
    ON (KLS.ESPCOD = E.ESPCOD AND KLS.BANCO = 'OLIM')

            '''
     alundisc = pd.read_sql(con = conn, sql = query)

finally:
    conn.close()
```

I am getting the following error every time I run the code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gilmar.melo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1586, in execute
    cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf3' in position 632: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If I don't put the line  alundisc = pd.read_sql(con = conn, sql = query), the code runs OK.

Comment: It is not a standart ascii character, what encoding are you using ?

Comment: I'm using # -*- coding: latin-1 -*- in the beginning of code.

Comment: Check the cx_Oracle doc https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/globalization.html